# Modeling Zero or One to Zero or One Relationship? Is that a thing?

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database

I've hit a wall trying to find the right design for a relational database that I'm working with.

**DEFINITIONS:**

- Client: A person who comes into a Shop to get a Service.
- User: A person who executes a Service required by the Client.
- Appointment: An agreement between a Client and a User to be at a Shop's location at a specific moment in time.
- Shop: A set of Users who offer
  services in a location.
- Service: A technical process

**Use cases I'm trying to support:**

- A Client calls the Shop and sets an Appointment to get a Service from
  a User.
- A Client walks into a the Shop's location and requires a
  Service from a User.

**Problem:**
A Service has a relationship with Client and User, but so does the Appointment which (when one actually exists) is also related to the Service.

So, if an Appointment is created, it doesn't feel right to create an empty Service because the Appointment might or might not actually come through, and I think the Service would have a ton of empty rows created just to support Appointments. Also a Service is not a Service just if it's got a User, a Client and an Appointment, it requires some other attributes to be a valid Service.

I also think that repeating the User and Client in both the Appoitment and Service is not right because I might have some integrity problems to deal with in the future.

What would be the right approach to this problem?

Comment: What is the relationship between Service and Appointment? Can an Appointment be for one, multiple, and/or zero Services? Can you have a Service without an Appointment? (For walk-ins, any reason not to make a "dummy" appointment?) Do you have to track walk-ins where a service could note be done due to lack of qualified users?

Comment: The Service may or may not have an Appointment. Yes, you can have a Service without an Appointment. The reason's I've got to not make a dummy appointment are, 1. There's not an actual Appointment happening for walk-ins, 2. Reporting/metrics ex. percentage of cancelled Appointments, 3. Appointment times business rules. But I'm still not completely convinced that these reasons are enough to not consider dummy appointments. I haven't thought of tracking non completed walk-ins, I think it'll be necessary at some point, my plan was to create future Appointment if all qualified Users are busy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’d start with the following and adapt as new business rules came up.

First, the “base” tables for Clients, Shopes, Users, and Services (the work that could be done)

```
CLIENT
 ClientId
 Name
 ContactInformation

SHOP
 ShopId
 Name
 OtherAttribues

USER
 UserId
 ShopId  
 Name
 Etc

 (Note: Assumes a user works in only one shop, otherwise you need a many-to-many
  table joining SHOP and USER. See further reminders below.)

SERVICE
 ServiceId
 Name
 FurtherAttributes

 (This is the “master list” of all available services that can be done. “ServiceEvent”
  is used to record actual work being done.)
```

Next, the complex tables:

```
SERVICEEVENT
 ServiceEventId
 ClientId  (who the work was done for)
 UserId  (who did the work work. Add ShopId if a User can work in multiple shops)
 ServiceId  (what work was done)
 FurtherAttributes  (time, cost, etc.)

(This is used to record actual work that was done--or perhaps, is being done?)

APPOINTMENT
 AppointmentId
 ClientId   (who the work will be done for)
 UserId     (who will be doing the work. Add ShopId if a User can work in multiple shops.)
 ServiceId  (What work will be done)
 ServiceEventId  NULLABLE  (the ServiceEvent, if any, produced by this Appointment)
 Status     (indicate pending, cancelled, completed, etc.)
 FurtherAppointmentAttributes   (when the appointment was made, etc.)
 FurtherServiceEventAttributes  (optional? data used to populate ServiceEvent, when it comes time to do so)

(Should consider creating a lookup table for "Status".)
```

“Appointment” and “ServiceEvent” really are two distinct things. They look similar, but each can exist without the other (cancelled appointments, walk-in service event), and so both need all the keys. ServiceEvents generated via Appointments should be created by a routine that reads the data from the Appointment and INSERTs that into ServiceEvent.

The link (foreign key) between them could be in either table; I put it in Appointment, as ideally every Appointment produces a ServiceEvent, but the reverse is not true.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was thinking of doing, but it just feels weird to have the Client and User relationship in both tables. Thank you for the Status table suggestion, we have a known value set for both appointment status and service status, we're currently handling it as attributes for the tables. Is there any scalability issues that might come up by implementing this model? Why would it be better to have the foreign key set in the Appointment, would that yield better performance? And again, thanks a lot!

Comment: I put the foreign key in Appointment because then it isn't in ServiceEvent, because ServiceEvent seems likely to be the bigger table. The (hopefully vast) majority of Appointments will have matching ServiceEvents, and there will be (many?) walk-in ServiceEvents. Make that table smaller, performance is improved. Mind you now, with one four-byte column, it will take a LOT of activity for that performance difference to be noticeable by humans, but still.

Comment: As for scaling, the tables seem solid to me, given what you've told us about the problem set. Indexes should be your next focus, and that depends entirely on the queries you'll be running against the tables--or at least, the ones you know will need to perform well.

Comment: Is having the foreign key only in the "Appointments" table going to affect if I try to get the "Appointment" of a specific "ServiceEvent"? and why not have the "AppointmentId" in the "ServiceEvent" table?

Comment: Short answer: No.

Comment: Longer answer: As you have described them, there are different things--think equals, or peers. An Appointment may  have (lead to, generate) a ServiceEvent, and a ServiceEvent may have (been created because of) an Appointment, but neither relation is necessary or required. This provides argument for each to have an FK referencing the other. But, if they both have FKs, you could end up with A refs B, but B refs C, so best to just have the link in one table. If there is no related item, set the FK value to NULL. See my first comment for why I stuck it in the Appointment table.